# How to calculate deltas between two numeric nodes in two different data structures in Python?

Tags: python

I have a complicated data structure that is a roughly hierarchical dict, but with some lists thrown in a some levels (the serverStatus output of MongoDB)

How could I traverse the data structure of the current data sample and, whenever number is found at a certain point in the data structure, calculate the difference between that number, and the number from the same point in the data structure of the previous sample? (if it exists in the previous sample)

I was thinking about converting the data structure to {tag1.tag2.tag3... : value} then using tag1.tag2.tag3... as the key for doing the diffs.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm sure there's a much more Pythonic way of doing this, but here's what I came up with.  This is a recursive function to convert a hierarchical Python dictionary into a single level dictionary with the key value being a string like ".key1.key2.key3"

```
# Convert MongoDB serverStatus() output from :
# {
#   "host" : "myserver",
#   "version" : "4.x.x",
#   "process" : "mongouser",
#   "pid" : NumberLong(5236),
#   "uptime" : 457766,
#   "uptimeMillis" : NumberLong(457767459),
#   "uptimeEstimate" : NumberLong(457767),
#   "localTime" : ISODate("2020-07-27T21:15:06.901Z"),
#   "asserts" : {
#                 "regular" : 0,
#                 "warning" : 0,
#                 "msg" : 0,
#                 "user" : 458,
#                 "rollovers" : 0
#          ..snip...
# to (numbers below aren't from the same sample)
# {
#   ".host": "myserver",
#   ".version": "4.x.x",
#   ".process": "mongouser",
#   ".pid": 5236,
#   ".uptime": 529644.0,
#   ".uptimeMillis": 529644987,
#   ".uptimeEstimate": 529644,
#   ".localTime": null,
#   ".asserts.regular": 0,
#   ".asserts.warning": 0,
#   ".asserts.msg": 0,
#   ".asserts.user": 458,
#   ".asserts.rollovers": 0,
#   ...snip...
#                 
def py_struct_to_dot_struct(py_struct,dot_struct,dot_struct_key=""):
  if( type(py_struct) in [dict] ):
      for key in py_struct:
          if( type(py_struct[key]) in [dict] ):
              py_struct_to_dot_struct( py_struct[key], dot_struct, dot_struct_key+"."+key )
          else:
              dot_struct[dot_struct_key+"."+key]=py_struct[key]
```

I could then just loop through the current sample py_struct by key1.key2... key string and calculate diffs vs the previous sample (if that key exists in the previous sample)

All feedback appreciated.